# Extract specific word

Tags: r, regex, bioinformatics

I have this list of objects:

```
  dput(head(annotations))
    structure(list(X1 = c("KQ415659.1", "KQ415659.1", "KQ415659.1", 
    "KQ415659.1", "KQ415659.1", "KQ415659.1"), X2 = c("Genbank", 
    "Genbank", "Genbank", "Genbank", "Genbank", "Genbank"), X3 = c("exon", 
    "exon", "exon", "exon", "exon", "exon"), X4 = c(2986, 8779, 12123, 
    14982, 15303, 15780), X5 = c(3040, 8886, 12182, 15050, 15387, 
    15844), X6 = c(".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."), X7 = c("+", "+", 
    "+", "+", "+", "+"), X8 = c(".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."), X9 = c("transcript_id \"rna0\"; gene_id \"gene0\"; gene_name \"ICBIM_22028242mg\";", 
    "transcript_id \"rna0\"; gene_id \"gene0\"; gene_name \"ICBIM_22028243mg\";", 
    "transcript_id \"rna0\"; gene_id \"gene0\"; gene_name \"ICBIM_22028244mg\";", 
    "transcript_id \"rna0\"; gene_id \"gene0\"; gene_name \"ICBIM_22028245mg\";", 
    "transcript_id \"rna0\"; gene_id \"gene0\"; gene_name \"ICBIM_22028246mg\";", 
    "transcript_id \"rna0\"; gene_id \"gene0\"; gene_name \"ICBIM_22028247mg\";"
    )), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
    -6L))
```

I want to extract the  word that starts with "ICBIM" and ends with "mg" from all the strings.

```
# A tibble: 6 x 1
  X9                                                                          
<chr>
        1 "transcript_id \"rna0\"; gene_id \"gene0\"; gene_name \"ICBIM_22028241mg\";"
        2 "transcript_id \"rna0\"; gene_id \"gene0\"; gene_name \"ICBIM_22028242mg\";"
        3 "transcript_id \"rna0\"; gene_id \"gene0\"; gene_name \"ICBIM_22028243mg\";"
        4 "transcript_id \"rna0\"; gene_id \"gene0\"; gene_name \"ICBIM_22028244mg\";"
        5 "transcript_id \"rna0\"; gene_id \"gene0\"; gene_name \"ICBIM_22028245mg\";"
        6 "transcript_id \"rna0\"; gene_id \"gene0\"; gene_name \"ICBIM_22028246mg\";"
```

Comment: Check out `help("regex")` and (for example) `help("gsub")`

Comment: Provide reproducible example: `dput(head(myData))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex in `sub`:

```
sub(".*\\b(ICBIM.+mg)\\b.*", "\\1", annotations$X9)
# [1] "ICBIM_22028242mg" "ICBIM_22028243mg" "ICBIM_22028244mg" "ICBIM_22028245mg"
# [5] "ICBIM_22028246mg" "ICBIM_22028247mg"
```

Here, `\\b` indicates a word border.

Answer (score 2):

Regex matching in R is a bit weird. You have a 6 functions (`grep`, `grepl`, `sub`, `gsub`, `regexpr`, `gregepr`, `regexec`) doing related things, but none of them returns the actual string. The closest thing you can get is a list of match positions and lengths from (for example) `regexpr` that can be passed to  `regmatches` to get the strings.

So here is how I would do it:

```
your_data = c("transcript_id \"rna0\"; gene_id \"gene0\"; gene_name \"ICBIM_22028241mg\";", "transcript_id \"rna0\"; gene_id \"gene0\"; gene_name \"ICBIM_22028242mg\";")
matches = regexpr("ICBIM.*mg", your_data)
regmatches(your_data, matches)
[1] "ICBIM_22028241mg" "ICBIM_22028242mg"
```

Answer (score 0):

> starts with "ICBIM" and ends with "mg"

```
ICBIM.+?mg
```

[See the regex demo](https://regexr.com/49jcj)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming format of rows are the same, without *regex*:

```
substring(annotations$X9, 51, 66)
# [1] "ICBIM_22028242mg" "ICBIM_22028243mg" "ICBIM_22028244mg" "ICBIM_22028245mg" "ICBIM_22028246mg" "ICBIM_22028247mg"

read.fwf(textConnection(annotations$X9), widths = c(50, 16), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)[, 2]
# [1] "ICBIM_22028242mg" "ICBIM_22028243mg" "ICBIM_22028244mg" "ICBIM_22028245mg" "ICBIM_22028246mg" "ICBIM_22028247mg"
```